# How Postgres deals with concurrent data update with different isolation levels?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions

For example, 2 transactions updating the same column in table, but with different values

```
update user set user.name = <value> where user.id = 1;
```

What would be with first and second transaction, if transaction isolation levels are READ COMMITTED, REPEATABLE READ, SERIALIZABLE? In what conditions will we see the rollback?

Comment: "...2 transactions updating the same column..." -- The first one wins. It would automatically acquire a lock on the row due to the update. REPEATABLE READ and SERIALIZABLE transactions will wait untile the lock is released by the other transaction (when it ends).

Comment: But again, this is really easy to try. Just open two connections to the database from your favorite SQL tool and raise or lower the isolation levels before running the updates. Easy peasy.

Comment: Read [Concurrency Control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html).